# How To Set of PDF page Width Height in Headless Chrome

Tags: laravel, pdf, pdf-generation, google-chrome-headless

Using Headless Chrome we can generate **PDF** using the following Commands. here the problem is I am trying to pass the Width and Height of the **PDF** but it is not working.

`google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --nosandbox --print-to-pdf https://gf.dev/ --print-to-pdf-height=100in  --print-to-pdf-width=200in --print-to-pdf-no-header`

`google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf --paperWidth=2 --paperHeight=2 https://gf.dev/`

Thanks In Advance